# Computing operator norm $\ell_p\ni(x_n)\longrightarrow T(x_n)=(a_nx_n)\in\ell_q$, $q<p$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I want to compute the norm of the operator $T:\ell_p\longrightarrow\ell_q$ with $1\leqslant q<p<\infty$, defined by $T(x_n)=(a_nx_n)$. By hypothesis $T$ is a bounded linear operator. My initial doubt is what conditions must satisfy $a=(a_n)\in\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}$ for that to be true. I think I can prove that $T$ is a bounded linear operator iff $(a_n)\in\ell_s$ where $s=pq/(p-q)$ using Hölder's inequality. If my reasoning is correct I know that $\|T\|\leqslant\|a\|_s$. But I have no idea how to go on from there. Any hint?

Apologies in advance for my English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $T$ is  abounded operator iff $(a_n) \in \ell_{s}$ where $s=\frac {pq} {p-q}$ and the operator norm is $\|T\|=(\sum |a_n|^{s})^{1/s}$. This can be proved using Holder's inequality and condition for equality in Holder's inequality: choose $x_n$ to be of the form $\pm |a_n|^{\alpha}$ for  a suitable $\alpha$ to see that the norm is exactly $\|(a_n)\|_s$.

Recall that $\|T\| \geq \frac {\|Tx\|} {\|x\|}$ for any non-zero $x$, in particular for the suggested sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: So I have something wrong with my $s$. But using your $r$ and Hölder I get $(\sum|a_nx_n|^q)^{1/q}\leqslant(\sum|a_n|^{qr})^{1/qr}(\sum|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$. And $s=qr$. I suppose there is something I'm not seeing...

Comment: @JuanCastaño I had made a mistake in my calcuation. Your value of $s$ is right. I have given hint for showing that the norm is exactly $\|a\|_s$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have it now. If I'm not wrong, I can get the desired result for $\alpha=\frac{q}{p-q}=\frac{s}{p}$.

Comment: @JuanCastaño You are right.